# How can I create custom roxygen2 tags for a package?

Tags: r, documentation, roxygen2

I'm aware of this documentation (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/extending.html) but I am struggling to make it work for a custom "home brew" package. All I really need is a "simple" custom tag e.g. `@information`. There seems to be some information missing to bridge the gap (for me) between the documentation and actually having it work in a package (a working example would be great).

I also found this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcibRDNSfoM
and related repositories:
https://github.com/shahronak47/informationtag
https://github.com/shahronak47/infotagdemo
However, they also don't seem to be doing what I would expect.

Can anyone point me at some useful examples?

Comment: I would expect `information` (https://github.com/shahronak47/infotagdemo/blob/master/R/demo.R#L2) to show up in the Rd file (https://github.com/shahronak47/infotagdemo/blob/master/man/test.Rd).

Comment: Also the "fast forward" `devtools::document()` in RStudio seems to ignore custom tags. It will only be processed if I manually put `devtools::document(roclets = c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace', 'informationtag::information_roclet'))` into the R console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaning on the example made with the `@tip` tag in the [Extending roxygen2 vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/extending.html) for a simple descriptive tag `@information` all you need to do is create a file in the `R/` folder of your package and add this content to the file:

```
#' @importFrom roxygen2 roxy_tag_parse
#' @importFrom roxygen2 roxy_tag_rd
NULL

# define a roxy_tag_parse() method that describes how to parse the tag 
# text. Here it will be processed using Markdown 
#' @export
roxy_tag_parse.roxy_tag_information <- function(x) {
  roxygen2::tag_markdown(x)
}

# define a roxy_tag_rd() method that describes how to convert the tag 
# into `.Rd` commands 
#' @export
roxy_tag_rd.roxy_tag_information <- function(x, base_path, env) {
  roxygen2::rd_section("information", x$val)
}

# Since we provided our own type "information" in rd_section() we need 
# to define a format method for this type
# Feel free to adapt this method to your needs
#' @export
format.rd_section_information <- function(x, ...) {
  paste0(
    "\\section{Information}{\n",
    "\\itemize{\n",
    paste0("  \\item ", x$value, "\n", collapse = ""),
    "}\n",
    "}\n"
  )
}
```

Later on you can just use the tag as any other tag in your roxygen headers:

```
#' @information This is some important information I want to display!
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

If you want to create a separate package for custom roclets and import them when needed, then in your custom package `{myroclets}` create a file in `R/` and add the same contents as stated above. Additionally you need to add a constructor for your `@information` tag so append the file with

```
#' @export
information_roclet <- function() {
  roxygen2::roclet("information")
}
```

to export your `information_roclet`.

In the case you need to use the `information_roclet` in another package of yours, just add to DESCRIPTION

```
Roxygen: list(roclets = c("collate",
                          "rd",
                          "namespace",
                          "myroclets::information_roclet"),
              packages = "myroclets")
```

where `myroclets` is the package where the `information_roclet` was originally created.